# Zoom and pan HTML5 canvas - library

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, zooming

I'm trying to implement zooming and panning a canvas which contains a picture. 
I found this example http://phrogz.net/tmp/canvas_zoom_to_cursor.html, but the transformations are applied on the picture withing the canvas, not on the canvas itself. 
I don't understand the code completely, so I didn't manage to customize it for my needs.
Can someone help me with that?

Or, if you could recommend me some good library suitable for my needs, that would be great.
Thanks.

Comment: why do you need to move the canvas itself rather than an image inside the canvas?

Comment: Because I have two overlaying canvas elements, one for holding the picture and the other one for drawing on it. So when the picture is moved/zoomed, the other canvas should follow.

Answer (score 12):

**Check out the transformation methods available on the context object.**

`Context.scale` will allow you to scale your content.

`Context.translate` will allow you to offset the drawing of your content to create your panning effect.

If you want 2 overlaying canvases to maintain their aspect ratio then you would scale & translate both canvases by the same amount.

Here's example code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/H6UMN/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    #wrapper{position:relative;}
    canvas{position:absolute; border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var canvas1=document.getElementById("canvas1");
    var ctx1=canvas1.getContext("2d");

    var $canvas=$("#canvas");
    var canvasOffset=$canvas.offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;
    var scrollX=$canvas.scrollLeft();
    var scrollY=$canvas.scrollTop();
    var cw=canvas.width;
    var ch=canvas.height;

    var scaleFactor=1.00;
    var panX=0;
    var panY=0;

    var circleX=150;
    var circleY=150;
    var radius=15;

    drawTranslated();

    $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
    $("#scaledown").click(function(){ scaleFactor/=1.1; drawTranslated(); });
    $("#scaleup").click(function(){ scaleFactor*=1.1; drawTranslated(); });
    $("#panleft").click(function(){ panX-=10; drawTranslated(); });
    $("#panright").click(function(){ panX+=10; drawTranslated(); });

    function drawTranslated(){

        ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(panX,panY);
        ctx.scale(scaleFactor,scaleFactor);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(circleX-radius,circleY-radius,radius*2,radius*2);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fillStyle="blue";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.restore();

        ctx1.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
        ctx1.save();
        ctx1.translate(panX,panY);
        ctx1.scale(scaleFactor,scaleFactor);
        ctx1.beginPath();
        ctx1.arc(circleX,circleY,radius,0,Math.PI*2);
        ctx1.closePath();
        ctx1.fillStyle="red";
        ctx1.fill();
        ctx1.restore();
    }

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id=scaledown>Scale Down</button>
    <button id=scaleup>Scale Up</button>
    <button id=panleft>Pan Left</button>
    <button id=panright>Pan Right</button><br>
    <div id=wrapper>
        <canvas id="canvas" width=350 height=300></canvas>
        <canvas id="canvas1" width=350 height=300></canvas>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```